# Check if each Column in pandas DF is only values [ 0-9]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to scan a column in a df that only contains values that have 0-9. I want to exclude or flag columns in this dataframe that contain aplha/numerical

```
df_analysis[df_analysis['unique_values'].astype(str).str.contains(r'^[0-9]*$', na=True)]
```

Comment: Can you just apply the above code to each column to get a list of applicable columns?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"string": ["asdf", "lj;k", "qwer"], "numbers": [6, 4, 5], "more_numbers": [1, 2, 3], "mixed": ["wef", 8, 9]})

print(df.select_dtypes(include=["int64"]).columns.to_list())
print(df.select_dtypes(include=["object"]).columns.to_list())
```

Create dataframe with multiple columns. Use .select_dtypes to find the columns that are integers and return them as a list. You can add "float64" or any other numeric type to the include list.

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: No Im sorry if my question is off.... I want to scan unique values of each column and see if it only contains 0-9 not filter columns that are numerical already

Comment: @Tinkinc , it greatly help and efficient, when question is reproducible along with the expected output  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are you loading data of mixed type for a given column? So row 1-10 are strings, but 11-15 are meant to be integers and are being interpreted as strings?

Comment: I am going to reword this example

Comment: Pandas can store columns as specific dtypes or mixed objects. Columns with mixed data types will be objects. So my answer is basically the same as before, but you would replace "int64" with "object" to get a list of the columns that don't have numerical type. This might include strings or strings and numbers, or any other object, but not exclusively int64 or float64, etc.